How to add up values from a column if two conditions are true? One is a date and the other a keyword
I've been trying to find a way to do this but is not working as I need, if it's even possible. I have a table like this:



Column A
Column B
Column C




1/1/2000
qwe
2


2/1/2000
asd
3


3/1/2000
zxc
4



I need to add up the numbers on column C, if the day on column A is less or equal to a number and I need to also only add up numbers if the word on column B match a keyword.
In this example the day could be less than 2, and the keyword "e".
I should get a result of 2, but it doesn't work.
I tried with =SUMPRODUCT((C1:C3)*(DAY(A1:A3)<=2)*(B1:B3="=*e*")) and =IF(DAY(A1:A3)<=2,SUMIF(B1:B3,"=*e*",C1:C3))
Thanks in advance.

Are all dates in same year and same month?

SUMPRODUCT version you might be more familiar with:
=SUMPRODUCT(
    (DAY(Table1[Column A])<=2) *
    (ISNUMBER(SEARCH("e",Table1[Column B]))) *
    (Table1[Column C]))

Or SUMIFS version
=SUMIFS(C:C, A:A, "<=" & DATE(YEAR(A2), MONTH(A2), 2), B:B, "*e*")

And to really bring it home (I'm away from Excel365 so it might be wrong but you get the idea).  If it's worth doing, it's worth doing with LET:
=LET(
    rangeA, Table1[Column A],
    rangeB, Table1[Column B],
    rangeC, Table1[Column C],
    dayCondition, LAMBDA(x, IF(DAY(x) <= 2, 1, 0)),
    textCondition, LAMBDA(y, IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("e", y)), 1, 0)),
    filteredSum, LAMBDA(a, b, c, IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(dayCondition(a) * textCondition(b) * c), 0)),
    result, filteredSum(rangeA, rangeB, rangeC),
    result
)

Would love to see even more convoluted applications of LET/LAMBDA and such.


Thank you very much, the first fourmula worked as I need it.

If all dates are in same year and same month as the first date, then SUMIFS should be preferred. This is most compatible. And the criteria already supports wildcard character *.
Example:

Formula in H2 translated:
=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,"<"&DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2),F2),B:B,"*"&F3&"*")

If you are on Microsoft 365, a combination of SUM and FILTER may be used.
Formula in J2 of my example translated:
=SUM(FILTER(C:C,(DAY(N(A:A))<F2)*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(F3,B:B)))))

As you see the most challenging is the contains-search as FILTER not supports any wildcard character in criteria. Alt least not, that I am aware of. Maybe another answer will show.
The ISNUMBER(SEARCH(F3,B:B)) part uses SEARCH which returns the position of first occurrence of the searched in the string and else #VALUE error, which is not a number.
The N(A:A) part get used to avoid #VALUE error when tried to get the DAY out of a not numeric value.
As you are unclear in your question about whether the day shall be less than or less or equal than a search criterion, my formulas filter less than.  Replace the < with <= to change that.
